# Call a Flask function every few minutes

Tags: python, html, flask

On my HTML page I've got a span that gets the value of the function getStatus():

```
<span id="sysStatus" style="font-weight: bold;">{{ status }}</span>
```

The function that returns status:

```
def getStatus():
    state = database().getState()
    if state:
        status = " On"
    else:
        status = "Off"
    return status
```

Rendering the html page:

```
class Tongles(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('page.html', status=getStatus())
```

I would like somehow to dynamically refresh the status of the system, and the text on the span.

How can I recall the function getStatus without reloading the whole page?

Comment: Flask applications are different than normal Python apps. Cause they have to update and the HTML part. I can easily execute the Python function every few minutes, but the point its to dynamically update the span text which is an indication for the user.

Comment: Theoretical solution: make a special flask handler to return specifically the status then in client side please ajax to query the status periodically.

Comment: You could either use sockets or poll the server for `getStatus` using AJAX requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**flask_app.py** add a route to your getStatus method

```
...
@app.route("/myStatus")
def getStatus():
    state = database().getState()
    if state:
        status = " On"
    else:
        status = "Off"
    return status
 ...
```

**page.html** use ajax callbacks to populate the div with jquery(or something else if you want)

```
...

<span id="sysStatus" style="font-weight: bold;">{{ status }}</span>

...
...

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("ajaxd()",10000); // call every 10 seconds
});

function ajaxd() { 
  //reload result into element with id "sysStatus"
  $("#sysStatus").load("/myStatus", function() {  alert( "Load was performed." ); });

}
</script>

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jorn, But it doesnt seems to work into my app. I'll try to figure it out, though.

Comment: Actually I put a print inside the getStatus function to check whether the function has been called from the script but, it doesnt.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and I removed the r from the url from the first moment. But still, It doesnt call recall the function every  10 secs. Im think to try to return the state using jsonify. What do you think? Is it necessary ?

Comment: you should just be able to load it ... and it should call it every 10 seconds ...

Comment: I added an alert to the load so you should be able to see the alert when new content loads ... it looks like I may have had unballanced parenthesis before so maybe the function crashed ...

Comment: I know why but the function its been called just once, only upon page reloading.

Comment: try changing it to `setInterval(ajaxd,10000);` and see if that works

Comment: Thanks for your time Joran. But unfortunately still no result.

Comment: On the browser's console, Im getting an error : [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $global code                                      which its points on the line $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: you need to use jquery ... they have a public cdn ... you need to put the proper include headers in the head section of the html

Comment: You're right, I had it on the bottom. Thank you very much Joran. Your answer will be marked as accepted!