# How can I yield a template over another in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have been working on a project in flask and I am stuck on one part where I need to figure out how to yield one flask template over another.

To illustrate what I mean, for example, I have a program like this.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, stream_with_context, Response, render_template
app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    def generate():
        yield render_template('index.html')
        yield render_template('index2.html')
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

index.html

```
<h3>Hi</h3>
```

index2.html

```
<h3>Bye</h3>
```

Running main.py returns:

```
Hi
Bye
```

Even though this makes sense, my goal is to make it result in just `Bye` which should replace `Hi`. I tried other paths like returning both but none of them worked. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: I don't think you understand how a generator works... It needs to be called through either an iteration or via a `next`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Right, that's what I thought too, that the usage of a generator was incorrect in this situation but when I returned two files without a generator, only the first file's contents were visible. If you don't mind, can you show me what you mean when you say to utilize an iteration or the `next` function in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do you function different to use a generator like this.

```
from flask import Flask, stream_with_context, Response, render_template
app = Flask('app')

def page_generator():
    yield render_template('index.html')
    yield render_template('index2.html')
generator_obj = None

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    global generator_obj
    generator_obj = generator_obj or page_generator()
    return Response(stream_with_context(next(generator_obj)))

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I don't know for sure if this will work in flask.
Note that after you call `hello_world` twice this will fail unless you reset `generator_obj` to `None` on `StopIteration`.

Comment: It works as in `Hi` shows up and then I have to reload to show `Bye`. Any clue on how to do this without the reloading?

Comment: Thats how a generator works... It need to call the method twice... If you want to load a second page after a certain period of time, you should google something along those line.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help. I'll accept this answer cause it did help me fix my problem to load the second template.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073789/8150685 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27722402/8150685

Answer (score 7):

It's not your case, but if you'd like to stream a template with static content, here's a way to do it. I'll be using the `sleep()` method to suspend the execution for 1 second.

```
from flask import Flask, stream_with_context, request, Response, flash
import time
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.disable_buffering()
    return rv

data = ['Hi', 'Bye']

def generate():
    for item in data:
        yield str(item)
        sleep(1)

@app.route('/')
def stream_view():
    rows = generate()
    return Response(stream_with_context(stream_template('index.html', rows=rows)))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

where **templates/index.html**:

```
{% for item in rows %}
<h1>{{ item }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

See [streaming from templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/#streaming-from-templates) in the documentation.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to add a link for a similar thing but video streaming. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask